# Android Volley Library with GSON , How Convert Json Object to Array

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am getting Data from API, Some fields are in json object i want to convert it to json Arry. I can't modify the json but i can store it as json Array.

I already created the pojo classes. Now in json Response 4 product are coming , in future it will increase the list so by json object i can't get the values of product.

**My Json Response:**

```
   {
"SKU": [
    "Hydrangea White( F033 )",
    "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )",
    "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )",
    "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )",

],
"wherehouse3": {
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "data": [
        20,
        14.583333333333,
        13.541666666667,
        12.5,

    ],
    "qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 70,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 50,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 50,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 25,

    },
    "cunsumption_time": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 0,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 0,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 0,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 0,

    },
    "sold_qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 480,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 350,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 325,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 300,

    },
    "projected_inventry": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,

    ],
    "recived_inventry": [
        1120,
        525,
        2953,
        900,

    ],
    "sku": [
        "F033",
        "F075",
        "F074",
        "F072",

    ],
    "productname": [
        "Hydrangea White",
        "Pink Rose 50 cm",
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm",
        "White Rose 50 cm",

    ]
  }
 }
```

In the above json Response  `qty`, `cunsumption_time`, `sold_qty` are in objects as below :

```
"qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 70,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 50,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 50,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 25,

    },
    "cunsumption_time": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 0,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 0,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 0,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 0,

    },
    "sold_qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 480,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 350,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 325,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 300,

    },
```

I want to store vaules of above json like below :

```
"qty": [
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 70,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 50,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 50,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 25,

    ],
    "cunsumption_time": [
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 0,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 0,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 0,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 0,

    ],
    "sold_qty": [
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 480,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 350,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 325,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 300,

    ],
```

**Fragment Code :**

```
 HighVelocityPojo highVelocityPojo;
 ArrayList<Top_10_BouquitShowPojo> graphList;

 private void JsonRequestGraph() {

    utils.showDialog();

    String url = Constants.TOP_10_BOUQUIT_HV+"days="+time+"&warehouse_id="+whareHouse;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            response -> {
                Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
                try {

                    // Gson Code Here
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<HighVelocityPojo>() {
                    }.getType();

                    highVelocityPojo = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
                    Log.e("size", highVelocityPojo.getSKU().size() + "");

                    graphList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i=0; i<highVelocityPojo.getSKU().size();i++){
                        graphList.add(new Top_10_BouquitShowPojo(highVelocityPojo.getWherehouse3().getProductname().get(i), highVelocityPojo.getWherehouse3().getData().get(i)));
                        Log.e("i VALUE 0",""+i+"----"+graphList.size());

                        if(i == highVelocityPojo.getSKU().size()-1){
                            callGraphView();
                            Log.e("i VALUE",""+i);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception",""+e);
                    utils.hideDialog();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
               utils.hideDialog();

            }, error -> {

                Log.e("error",""+error.getMessage());
                utils.hideDialog();
            });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

}
```

**HighVelocityPojo :**

```
 public class HighVelocityPojo {

    @SerializedName("SKU")
    @Expose
    private List<String> sKU = null;
    @SerializedName("wherehouse3")
    @Expose
    private Wherehouse3_HV wherehouse3;

    public List<String> getSKU() {
        return sKU;
    }

    public void setSKU(List<String> sKU) {
        this.sKU = sKU;
    }

    public Wherehouse3_HV getWherehouse3() {
        return wherehouse3;
    }

    public void setWherehouse3(Wherehouse3_HV wherehouse3) {
        this.wherehouse3 = wherehouse3;
    }

    }
```

**WhareHouse3_HV:**

```
public class Wherehouse3_HV {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Double> data = null;
    @SerializedName("qty")
    @Expose
    private Qty_HV qty;
    @SerializedName("cunsumption_time")
    @Expose
    private CunsumptionTime_HV cunsumptionTime;
    @SerializedName("sold_qty")
    @Expose
    private SoldQty_HV soldQty;
    @SerializedName("projected_inventry")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> projectedInventry = null;
    @SerializedName("recived_inventry")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> recivedInventry = null;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private List<String> sku = null;
    @SerializedName("productname")
    @Expose
    private List<String> productname = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...........
```

**Qty_HV :**

```
public class Qty_HV {

    @SerializedName("10 Blue Dendrobium Orchids( Z8363 )")
    @Expose
    private Integer _10BlueDendrobiumOrchidsZ8363;
    @SerializedName("Rose 6 St Orange Bqt in Foam Disks 50 cm ( Z8597 )")
    @Expose
    private Integer rose6StOrangeBqtInFoamDisks50CmZ8597;
    @SerializedName("5 Blue, 3 Purple, 2 Yellow D Orchids( Z8548 )")
    @Expose
    private Integer _5Blue3Purple2YellowDOrchidsZ8548;
    @SerializedName("12 Rainbow Roses( Z7031 )")
    @Expose
    private Integer _12RainbowRosesZ7031;

    public Integer get10BlueDendrobiumOrchidsZ8363() {
        return _10BlueDendrobiumOrchidsZ8363;
    }
     ..............
```

Comment: It should be done at api development, you have to modifiy your API response as per requirement

Comment: You are right @akshay, But they can't able to change because same API  using on Web. Do you have any suggestion  for this.

Comment: there are workarounds but it's not recommended